# Rsync command to synchronize two NTFS drives?

Tags: backup, rsync, ntfs

I have a 2 1.5TB drives containing numerous video, audio, documents etc that I would like to essentially mirror to 2 other drives for backup. I would like to do this using rsync (as it seems the most appropriate thing to use).

What command should I use to do so? Is there anything to be aware of when rsyncing NTFS partitioned drives/files?

EDIT:
To clarify I am running NTFS formatted drives in Kubuntu 10.04 machine. I am rsync'ing the drives from here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With rsync on unix, use --archive, and don't forget the --sparse and --hard-links options. I don't know if NTFS or the NTFS driver you use (ntfs-3g or kernel) supports sparse files and/or hardlinks, but it's good practice when using rsync for backups.

Also remember that --archive doesn't do --acls and --xattrs, but with NTFS, that doesn't matter.

I don't know how different rsync behaves on a Windows system, though.

Answer (score 8):

**To rsync between Linux ext4/xfs and windows ntfs mounts**

OR

**To rsync between two ntfs mounts :**

If the intent is to back-up the contents to ntfs mount using rsync and only transfer delta to ntfs partition, ***don't use rsync with archive (-a) option***.

rsync archive is equivalent to -rlptgoD and doesn't work with ntfs partition effectively.

Instead, try:

```
rsync -rvh --size-only --progress /path/to/ext4/ /path/to/ntfs/

rsync -rvh --size-only --progress /path/to/ntfs1/ /path/to/ntfs2/
```

Example:

```
[ram@thinkred1cartoon ~]$ df -PhT
Filesystem                       Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rhel-home            xfs       192G  175G   17G  92% /home
/dev/sdb2                        fuseblk   671G  564G  107G  85% /run/media/raman/Windows7_OS
/dev/sda2                        fuseblk   1.6T  513G  1.1T  32% /run/media/raman/Seagate

rsync -rvh --size-only --progress /home/ /run/media/raman/Windows7_OS/

rsync -rvh --size-only --progress /run/media/raman/Seagate/ /run/media/raman/Windows7_OS/
```

Where:

**`-r = recursive`**

**`--size-only = skip files that matches in size`**

```
-v = verbose          (optional)
-h = human readable   (optional)
--progress = progress (optional)
```

Here are some more [rsync hacks](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-rsync-hacks/answer/Raman-Kathpalia?share=68335132&srid=hfE13)

Comment: I used this but then found my timestamps weren't correct, so I reran it with `-t` to maintain timestamps. I also reran it with `--inplace` to attempt to avoid recopying all the data. It did seem to run much faster than the initial sync.

Comment: @raman-kathpalia How do you preserve permissions, timestamps, group and ownership between two NTFS partitions with `rsync` ?

Comment: @SebMa With rsync, you can't AFAIK. Not at the time of writing this comment at least.

Comment: @TheClassic `-t` produces tons of errors of the form "failed to set times on..."

Comment: I think rsync with NTFS is not useful, because it cannot copy attributes, including file created date. I don't want a backup with lost all attributes.

Comment: @Kamil rsync does not preserve the attributes when NTFS is involved. Do you know which utility offers that feature while copying from Linux Filesystem to NTFS and vice-versa? I'm still on the hunt.

Comment: @RamanKathpalia Yea, I just realized that. Regarding the utility that offers such feature - `tar` or `gzip` can do that, but thats not real attribute translation between diffrent filesystems. Just a box that holds them properly.

Answer (score 4):

If the NTFS partitions are mounted on a *NIX device, rsync is good. If you runing Windos, take a look at ROBOCOPY.EXE (included in free downloadable Resource Kit Tools, if your edition of Windows does not already have it).

```
rsync -a source dest
```

is the basic comand, but you better read carefuly the documentation and make some tests before using it as a backup strategy

Answer (score 1):

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=c26efa36-98e0-4ee9-a7c5-98d0592d8c52&displaylang=en - **Microsoft SyncToy** 2.1 is a free application that synchronizes files and folders between locations.

Comment: SyncToy is a good tool for Windows, but the questioner is running Kubuntu. SyncToy might run in Wine on Linux; old test results https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19768 aren't promising, but Wine improves all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am probably late to the party, but I was having this issue, but fixed it with using new options on my `fstab` configuration file, and after a reboot it worked flawlessly!

This is what my `/etc/fstab` looks like (notice `noatime` and `big_writes`):

```
UUID="3AEEB210EEB1C503"  /mnt/PiDrive ntfs-3g rw,auto,users,permissions,noatime,async,big_writes uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0000 0 0
UUID="149022ED9022D550" /mnt/PiDriveBU ntfs-3g rw,auto,users,permissions,noatime,async,big_writes uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0000 0 0
```

And the `resync` command I was using:

```
 sudo rsync -rvh --size-only --progress  --exclude="*.part"  /mnt/PiDrive/Hyperspin/ /mnt/PiDriveBU/Hyperspin/
```

I went from 20-50kb/s to 20-30mb/s!